# Use table column value as calculation for result in another column

Tags: t-sql, calculation

I have a table with a column named "Calc" varchar(50). This column contains math calculations such as 1+1, 9*9, 10/2, 10-2 etc.
Is there way in an update query to apply this calculation from the column and output the result in the same table in the "Results" column varchar(50).

Comment: You can't do that in pure SQL. This would require dynamic SQL, which is much more complicated.

Comment: Only with dynamic SQL and that opens up a huge security concern that you will forever fighting to seal with a requirement like that. Normally storing such calculations, and then expected them to be calculating (by the SQL Instance) is the sign of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) due to an inherent design flaw.

Answer (score 0):

As you know by now, SQL Server does not have an EVAL() function, nor does it support macro substitution.

However, this can be done via dynamic SQL

**Example**

```
Create table #YourTable (id int,[Calc] varchar(150),Results varchar(150))
Insert Into #YourTable Values 
 (1,'1+1',null)
,(2,'9*9',null)
,(3,'10/2',null)
,(4,'10-2',null)
,(5,'datediff(DAY,''2018-01-01'',getdate())',null)  -- Added Just for Fun


Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select ',' + concat('(',ID,',',[Calc],')')
                                     From #YourTable  A
                                     For XML Path (''))
                                 ,1,1,'')
Exec('Update A set Results = B.Value
       From  #YourTable A
       Join ( Select * from (values ' + @SQL + ')A([ID],[Value]) ) B
         on A.ID = B.ID
       ')

Select *
 From  #YourTable
```

**The Updated Table**

```
id  Calc                                    Results
1   1+1                                     2
2   9*9                                     81
3   10/2                                    5
4   10-2                                    8
5   datediff(DAY,'2018-01-01',getdate())    1012
```